# Adding styles to the list element on hover to an element with different class

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation marked up in the following way:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="first-item"><a href="main.html"> Home </a></li>
    <li class="second-item"><a href="menu.html"> Menu </a></li>
    <li class="third-item"><a href="why-us.html">Why us? </a></li>
    <li class="fourth-item"><a href="contact.html"> Contact </a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

The way it is set up is third-item li has some styles (box shadow) added as it is the active element indicating where the user currently is. It also makes the rest of list elements more transparent.

On hover on any other li, I want the third-item li to have no box shadow and any element hovered on have some styles added, but it does not seem to be working by  using ul li:hover .third-item.

Here is the CSS:

```
ul li:not(.third-item) {
 opacity: 0.8;
}

ul li.third-item {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
}

ul li:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

ul li:hover .third-item {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: You cannot do it with just CSS. You will require Javascript.

Comment: Sure you can @ManojKumar, see my answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the rule `ul li:hover .third-item` you are targeting `.third-item` inside the `li:hover`. But that element doesn't exist.

Instead, hover on the parent `ul`.

So `ul li:hover .third-item` becomes `ul:hover .third-item`. As soon as you hover the list, the style of the third element gets overwritten.

That works, but you would probably like to have the hover effect on your third item, as well. Therefore, you'll need to add `ul:hover .third-item:hover` to the `ul li:hover` rule.

```css
ul li:not(.third-item) {
 opacity: 0.8;
}

ul li.third-item {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
}
ul li:hover,
ul:hover .third-item:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
ul:hover .third-item {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="first-item"><a href="main.html"> Home </a></li>
    <li class="second-item"><a href="menu.html"> Menu </a></li>
    <li class="third-item"><a href="why-us.html">Why us? </a></li>
    <li class="fourth-item"><a href="contact.html"> Contact </a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for a very good explanation - I've been always struggling with different targeting of classes on hover. Not any more though. :) Thanks once again @LinkinTED